# jQuery autocomplete box to flow out of SharePoint modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sharepoint, modal-dialog

I have an `asp:TextBox` that has a jQuery autocomplete attached to it, they are contained within a SharePoint `CommonModalDialog`. When typing in the text box the autocomplete pops up but is bigger than the remaining space in the modal dialog

[image]

How can I get the autocomplete to always be on top and show outside of the modal dialog?

```
    <div class="InputRow">
        <div class="InputCell InputCellKey"></asp:Label></div>
        <div class="InputCell InputCellValue">
            <asp:TextBox ID="tb" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
```